# c++, member thread object causes crash on structure deletion when it's running

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've got a player class that has a kick function where I need to wait for a bit and kick the player afterwards for reasons out of my control and I also need to not hold the function while I wait, so my problem is;
When the thread is done waiting and kicks the player, the disconnect event is risen and the memory for the player gets immediately freed, that causes the apparently unfinished thread to consistently cause a crash in that moment.

```
class Player
{
    public:
        Player();
        void kick();
        void kick(const char*, int color);

    protected:

        std::thread delaydKick_;

    private:
};

void Player::kick(){
    sampgdk_Kick(playerid); //tells API to kick the player
}


void Player::kick(const char* m, int color){
    sendMessage(m, color); // sends message to the player using API
    delaydKick_ = std::thread([p = this](){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        p->kick(); //calls the function from the player object defined above
    });
    sampgdk::logprintf("Kicked (%s); %s", playername, m); //sends log to the server using API
}

//gets called by API when player disconnects
//PlayerDisconnectEvent just contains a pointer to the player which is on the heap
bool VirtualServerManager::OnPlayerDisconnect(PlayerDisconnectEvent&& e){
        //if disconnect is not kick
        if(e.player != nullptr){
            if( ( e.reason  < 2 ) && ( e.player->loggedIn == true ) ){
                e.player->getRefresh();
                e.player->updatePlayTime();
                SQLHandler sqlh(&sqlc);
                PlayerPersistance::save(e.player, &sqlh);
            }
            players.del(e.player->playerid); //here the player gets deleted when the api rises the event
        }
        return true;
    }
```

deffinition of the function del:

```
    template <typename T>
    void List<T>::del(size_t index){
        if(index >= current_max_){
            throw "pointer out of range";
        }
        if(items_[index] != nullptr){
            delete items_[index]; // it just calls delete on the pointer which is on the heap
            items_[index] = nullptr;
            count_--;
        }

}
```

to be clarify, the memory on the heap for the player which contains a thread object gets deleted, therefore terminating the thread object (delaydKick_) which results in the following crash:

> terminate called without an active exception

trying to join the thread on the player's destructor results in:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
> what():  Resource deadlock avoided

Detaching the thread after creating it solves the issue, but I'd like to know why are these errors happening especially when I join the thread on the Player class destructor.
Also I'd like to know if there's a way of getting around this without detaching the thread from the player.

Comment: There is a lot of stuff going on in your question, not all of it as clear as it needs to be. What disconnect event? What memory gets freed? Where does the crash occur? What destructor join? None of this is obvious. Please try to come up with a [mcve].

Comment: is that better?

Comment: No, your code still relies on things like “VirtualServerManager”, which isn’t defined. Try putting together a new [mcve] which is actually compilable as-is and demonstrates the problem you’re asking about.

Comment: already got two very good answers, thank you for your time anyway :3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> trying to join the thread on the destructor just causes the thing to spit a resource deadlock exception which I don't understand since it's not trying to join itself it's trying to join a member object

```
delaydKick_ = std::thread([p = this](){
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    p->kick(); //calls the function from the player object defined above
});
```

Here `p->kick()` is executed while **still in the thread**. So if you delete your player in `p->kick()`, and call `join()` in the destructor, you're trying to have the thread join itself.

You probably have an event loop in your application, which processes events like socket messages.

What you could do is:

```
   delaydKick_ = std::thread([p = this](){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        some_thread_safe_queue.push(this)
    });

// ...

// In your application's event loop:

while (1) {
  // ...

  while (some_thread_safe_queue.size > 0) {
    auto to_kick = some_thread_safe_queue.pop();
    to_kick->kick();
  }
}
```

You can check also `co_await` and `co_async` which would do really well to handle your problem.

Comment: this gave me an Idea I think Imma just end up using a thread pool.
btw, events are risen by the API and they are completely synchronous.

Comment: Alright then. I was going to edit my answer saying you don't need threading at all if you have an event loop - just add the player with the time it needs to be kicked at into some structure that is processed in the event loop. Anyway good luck :)

Comment: I don't have an event loop, that is a better Idea, I didn't fall into that solution because the API requires synchronous event handling, but I can just create my own event since the player class I'm using interacts with the API and not the other way around.

thank you very much <3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a player identifier to another thread, you need to use some kind of identifier that is guaranteed to remain valid for the duration of the use of that identifier. One simple solution is to use a shared pointer and let the destruction of the last shared pointer implicitly deallocate the player.

Another solution is to use some kind of "player ID". When the new thread needs to access the player, it acquires a mutex and checks the global player tablet see if the ID is still valid.

But if you're going to write a server that handles multiple users, and those users need to interact with each other, you need to pick some method to allow different contexts to pass players to each other.

```
    delaydKick_ = std::thread([p = this](){
```

This thread takes a raw pointer. Don't use raw pointers in modern C++. But if you absolutely must for some reason, you'll have to track a reference counter or similar thing somewhere. And you'll have to protect that with some kind of synchronization.

Also, very bad things will happen if your `kick` function is called while a kick is already in progress for that same connection. You should check that.

I strongly recommend against combining destruction with any server-level state changes. Your player object should go to a "kicked" state when it's kicked and a "disconnected" state when it's disconnected. Destruction should take place when, and only when, all threads are done with manipulating the object and it has been removed from any global tracking structures that could allow other threads to find it. Using `std::shared_ptr` does all this for you.

Comment: thank you very much for your advice I'm going to keep this in mind and probably going to change a bit of code considering what you just said, (this is the first real app I create on c++).

Comment: @RafaelLópez consider using a `weak_ptr` when making a copy of the `shared_ptr` for the delayed kick (and then check its validity it as you process it), as you don't want to wait the whole three seconds if the player is kicked in the meantime